# Mobile Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

[image]Hello All,

I have a issue with my mobile navigation menu,

I used float:right for the navigation bar and used a burger style menu for the mobile devices,

The issue is that on the full screen size the menu goes from Home.... to Contact Us But for the menu for the mobile size it goes from  (top to bottom) Contact Us .... to Homeenter image description here

```
<nav><!--start of nav tag-->
            <span class="nav-btn"></span>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Media</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="sermons.html">Sermons</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#">Ministries</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Evangelism</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Youth</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                </ul><!--End of nav class ul tag-->
        </nav><!--End of nav tag-->





 /*Navigation a*/
    nav .nav li a:hover{
    color:yellow;
    background:black;
    transition:all 0.0s;
}

 /*Navigation a*/
    nav .nav li ul li a:hover{
    width:auto;
    color:yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:transparent;

}

     /*Navigation ul size of ul main menu on mobile*/
     .nav {
     width:60%;
     height:auto;
     background:black;
     line-height:50px;
     position:fixed;
     border-radius:0 0 20px 0;
}

 /*Navigation li size of li in mobile mode*/
    nav .nav li{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    float: none;
    background-color:gray;
    border-bottom:1px red solid;
}



 /*Navigation li size of li in mobile mode*/
    nav .nav li:last-child{
    border-radius:0 0 20px 0;
}

/*                                                                       sub menu background color*/
nav .nav li ul li{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:orange;
}

/*                                                                       BLACK PATCH MOBILE SIZE*/
nav .nav li ul{


     border-right:0px red solid;
      border-left:0px red solid;
}

/*Show submenu at hover                                                           sub test*/
    nav .nav li:hover ul {
    width:50%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    left:75px;
    top:10px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: What's the current code you have? 
What is the behavior that you want?

Comment: please post the html

Comment: My guess is you need to reverse the order of the menu elements and use float: left instead, but can't know for sure without seeing your html.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the order of your menu elements and use `float: left` instead of `float: right`.

When using a float, the first element is going to go to the side of the following element in the DOM order based on the direction of the float. Your menu looks correct on desktop because you have them listed in reverse order then float: right, so the first element goes to the right of the second and so on, but the list is backwards when the screen is too narrow to float.

You want to have the menu in the correct order, then use `float: left` so the first element goes to the left of the following element etc.

Comment: I've changing it to float left but no joy.  unless I'm doing it in the wrong place.

Comment: If i use float left, its starts on the left in large media, whats the easiest way of have in floated to the left but to have it on the right, should I use margin or is there a certain way to do that.

Comment: Did you also reverse the order of the menu items in the HTML markup? They should be in the order you want them to appear from top to bottom and right to left in the HTML. From your example markup the items look like they are in the opposite order from what you want.

Comment: Try making the `<li>` elements `display:inline-block` and then `text-align: right` on the `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

For mobile or tablet view you need to set media query

```
media only screen and (max-width:768px){
.nav li{ 
  width:100%; 
  display:block;
   float: none; 
   background-color:gray; 
   border-bottom:1px red solid; 
 }

}
```